# Requesting further review

Tags: support, moderation

Mods - I'm writing this in Meta because the site is limiting me from writing out my full request. Please re-review my answer to this question.: [First Arduino Uno - Immediate Problems](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62205/first-arduino-uno-immediate-problems/62206?noredirect=1#comment133601_62206)

A mod wrote "It is a question eliciting further information." 
Actually, it is a full answer. I pointed out some missing information that seemed - and was, in fact - relevant, AND I went on to offer the correct solution, *as stated by the OP!*: to load the missing drivers, which I had also located. I believe this is an/the appropriate answer. So did the OP as he stated in a followup comment. With the OP stating it solved his problem, how is this not an answer?!

You've asked me to review my answer, my flag, and the moderators' denial, and I have done so. Now I am asking you - *several of you, please* - to review all of the foregoing, and tell me why an answer, accepted in writing by the OP - still deserves to be demoted.

I am asking you restore restore my answer. It deserves a place next to other answers, and it/I deserves an opportunity to be upvoted and/or selected, just as does any other answer *that solves a problem* does.

On a site with the standing of Stack Exchange, please don't tell me that moderation is considered mistake-proof, is final, and may not be peer-reviewed. Without any intention of blowing my own horn, I ask you to review the all-time standings; I didn't just wander in here yesterday. Your users - my peers - apparently feel that I add some value here. In this case, the OP has stated so, too.

I believe this disagreement deserves an honest and fair review by both sides. I have thoroughly reviewed my contribution and I stand by it for all of the foregoing reasons. I am asking for a similar honest and thorough review of the facts by the moderation team.

Comment: write an answer now

Answer (score 7):

The proper sequence should have been:

1. Ask for more clarification in comments, and make suggestions
2. The OP tries them and confirms what works
3. You write an answer that details what turned out to be wrong, why it was wrong, and what the fix is.

What you did:

1. Write an answer that asked for more clarification, and made some suggestions.

What we did:

1. Convert your answer to fit the proper pattern.
2. Fend off your moaning.

Feel free, now parts 1 and 2 of the proper sequence have been completed, to fill in part 3 by writing a proper answer detailing what was wrong, what the fix is, and why that is the fix.

Answer (score 4):

Oh dear. There don't seem to be any winners here. I agree with Majenko that the first sentence of your answer would appear better put as a comment under the question. That is what comments under the question are for.

I don't see any problem with the rest of your answer except that it doesn't really address the "access denied" issue. However answers should not be deleted just because they are wrong. I suggest you make another answer which focusses on answering the question, and also put further queries about whether or not the OP has installed drivers as a comment.

I am going to remove comments which don't seem to be appropriate under our Code of Conduct.